# Elasticsearch rails gem: timeout when saving a document after changing index name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I'm trying to index a simple document using the elasticsearch gem, index is created successfully but I get a timeout error when I try to index a simple document (LogEntry) after changing the index name although connection to the search server is reachable through other commands, this happens on my production environment RHEL and not on my development machine Ubuntu

```
irb(main):001:0> REPOSITORY.index
=> "ip_logstreams_2014_8_29"
irb(main):002:0> tr = LogEntry.new msgtext: "hello"
=> #<LogEntry:0x0000001dd1dc48 @attributes={:msgtext=>"hello"}>
irb(main):003:0> REPOSITORY.create_index!
2014-08-30 00:52:51 +0200: HEAD http://10.74.123.70:9200/ip_logstreams_2014_8_29 [status:200, request:0.002s, query:n/a]
2014-08-30 00:52:51 +0200: < 
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> REPOSITORY.save(tr)
2014-08-30 00:53:00 +0200: POST http://10.74.123.70:9200/ip_logstreams_2014_8_29/log_entry [status:201, request:0.209s, query:n/a]
2014-08-30 00:53:00 +0200: > {"msgtext":"hello"}
2014-08-30 00:53:00 +0200: < {"_index":"ip_logstreams_2014_8_29","_type":"log_entry","_id":"N4XHKXeRTGmZfWql_C5Svw","_version":1,"created":true}
=> {"_index"=>"ip_logstreams_2014_8_29", "_type"=>"log_entry", "_id"=>"N4XHKXeRTGmZfWql_C5Svw", "_version"=>1, "created"=>true}
irb(main):029:0> REPOSITORY.index = "ip_logstreams_2014_8_30"
=> "ip_logstreams_2014_8_30"
irb(main):030:0> REPOSITORY.create_index!
2014-08-30 00:25:52 +0200: HEAD http://10.74.123.70:9200/ip_logstreams_2014_8_30 [status:404, request:0.002s, query:N/A]
2014-08-30 00:25:52 +0200: < 
2014-08-30 00:25:52 +0200: [404] 
2014-08-30 00:25:52 +0200: PUT http://10.74.123.70:9200/ip_logstreams_2014_8_30 [status:200, request:0.399s, query:n/a]
2014-08-30 00:25:52 +0200: > {"settings":{"number_of_shards":5,"analysis":{"analyzer":{"my_pattern":{"type":"custom","tokenizer":"keyword","filter":["url_ngram","lowercase"]}},"filter":{"url_stop":{"type":"stop","stopwords":["="]},"url_ngram":{"type":"nGram","min_gram":4,"max_gram":40}}}},"mappings":{"log_entry":{"properties":{"msgpriority":{"type":"string","analyzer":"snowball"},"msghostname":{"type":"string","analyzer":"snowball"},"msgtext":{"type":"string","analyzer":"my_pattern"},"msgdatetime":{"type":"date","include_in_all":false}}}}}
2014-08-30 00:25:52 +0200: < {"acknowledged":true}
=> {"acknowledged"=>true}
irb(main):031:0> REPOSITORY.save(tr)
2014-08-30 00:27:26 +0200: [Faraday::TimeoutError] Timeout::Error {:host=>"10.74.123.70", :port=>9200, :protocol=>"http"}
Faraday::TimeoutError: Timeout::Error
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2563:in `read_status_line'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2552:in `read_new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1320:in `block in transport_request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1317:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1317:in `transport_request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1294:in `request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1287:in `block in request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:746:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:80:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:39:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:21:in `block in perform_request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:102:in `perform_request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.4/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/index.rb:99:in `index'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/elasticsearch-persistence-0.1.4/lib/elasticsearch/persistence/repository/store.rb:21:in `save'
    from (irb):31
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require
```

Model

```
class LogEntry

  include Tire::Model::Persistence

  attr_accessor :msgtext, :msgdatetime, :msgpriority, :msghostname

  attr_reader :attributes

  def initialize(attributes={})
    @attributes = attributes
  end

  def to_hash
    @attributes
  end
end
```

Comment: Beginning to think it's a platform issue, will use tcpdump to troubleshoot if request is issued by the gem or not